# Sorry mime the second (mate-control-center vs. firefox)

Tags: debian, firefox, mate-desktop, mime-types

My OS is Debian stretch (mate Desktop) Since about 2 years I have a problem with default setting for application browser(in mate-control-center) and firefox.
whenever I let firefox set itselfs as default browser in (about:preferences) my prefered application settings in mate-control-center changed from firefox-esr to thunderbird for default browser. And the other way around.

Both seemed somehow registert

```
 alex@Taomon:~$ gvfs-mime  --query x-scheme-handler/http 
    Default application for 'x-scheme-handler/http': firefox-esr.desktop
    Registered applications:
        thunderbird.desktop
        firefox-esr.desktop
    Recommended applications:
        thunderbird.desktop
        firefox-esr.desktop
    alex@Taomon:~$
```

---

```
alex@Taomon:~$ gio mime x-scheme-handler/https
Default application for 'x-scheme-handler/https': firefox-esr.desktop
Registered applications:
    thunderbird.desktop
    firefox-esr.desktop
Recommended applications:
    thunderbird.desktop
    firefox-esr.desktop
alex@Taomon:~$
```

How can I remove thunderbird as registered application for  `x-scheme-handler/http`  and `x-scheme-handler/http`s. I hope then my Error will be gone  for good.

edit

In ubuntu (focal) is only firefox registert.

```
alex@Guilmon:~$ gio mime x-scheme-handler/http
Default application for “x-scheme-handler/http”: firefox.desktop
Registered applications:
        firefox.desktop
Recommended applications:
        firefox.desktop
alex@Guilmon:~$
```

there is also thunderbird as e-mail client installed.

Comment: Also present in bullseye live session.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if you actually tried the obvious one but have you set Firefox as your default browser in Preferred Application settings?

[image]

For me Firefox is set to default in Preferred Applications AND in Firefox.

Comment: Yes of course I did. But then I start firefox, it says I'm not your default browser wenn I click on set as default browser in mate-control-center modul prefered applications it is changed to thunderbird. In my case it is in system, because by my unmodified test user the same behavior. Maybe it is time for a fresh install after over a decade from release upgrades.

Comment: Ok I think I never clicked on set-as-default-browser I just clicked on the X and never had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

it turned out it was a bug in thunderbird.

[bugreport](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=854818)

After upgrading thunderbird to version 1:91.7.0-2~deb10u1 this behaviour is gone.